# convert celery worker file to binary using pyinstaller

Tags: python, celery, pyinstaller, worker

Is there a way we can convert a celery tasks file using pyinstaller and run it.

i am using pyinstaller --onefile taskfile.py

But how do i run this with celery worker command

Comment: Have you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. The below example is a sample code celery which starts on program execution

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('myapp', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//', fixups=[])


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start(argv=['-A', 'test_celery', 'worker'])
```

> 2. Need to install celery and pyinstaller python package

```
pip install pyinstaller 
pip install celery
```

> 3. Generate pyinstaller spec file

```
pyi-makespec file_name_for_celery_task.py
```

> 4. Generate binary file

```
pyinstaller file_name.spec
```

I hope this helps cheers !!!!!

Comment: That's very helpful! I saw you added `fixups=[]` , which helps with the pyinstaller hidden import of celery, but for some reason I still have some other hidden imports `celery.loaders.app` , any suggestion?

Comment: depending on the version you have to add all the missing modules to hidden imports. I have to add around 10 modules to hidden imports. All related to celery. Looks when pyinstaller scans through celery it misses some modules